# Flow container vertical align with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, alignment

I have a `Label` whose length changes as the program runs (the text is modified). And I am trying to set side-by-side this `Label` and an `PictureBox`. To do so, I did put them into a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

The problem is then that the two elements are not vertically aligned: they have different height.

I did not find a *VerticalAlign* property in the `FlowLayoutPanel` nor did I manage to modify the height of my `Label` (changing the font size is not an option).

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your image a static height or is this dynamic too?

Comment: @ShawnSteward The image has a static height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but I believe I found a way to get this to align how you want.

1. Use a `TableLayoutPanel`, make it 2 columns, 1 row.
2. Add a `Label` to the left cell, set it to *Dock: Fill*. Also set *TextAlign: MiddleLeft*.
3. Add a `PictureBox` to the right cell.  Set the *Anchor* to *None*.

This should give you a label on the left and a `PictureBox` on the right that will always be vertically centered.  Modify the properties of the `TableLayoutPanel` according to your needs.

Comment: Great idea! It works fine, but only with the `AutoSize` property of the `TableLayoutPanel` set to `True`. Otherwise it works fine at design time only, but looks buggy at runtime. Thanks a lot!